# Automatically open Powerpoint in presenter mode, on correct screens

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

We have a laptop that we only use to present an induction course which is just a powerpoint presentation.

We have a second screen hooked up and when the presentation opens up someone has to navigate to and hit the start presentation button, at that point and it opens in presenter view with the notes on the laptop and the presentation on the second screen.

What I'd like to be able to do is avoid that on element of interaction.

Is it possible to launch a power point directly into presentation mode with no additional user interaction?

Answer (score 4):

Save the file in **PowerPoint Show (*.ppsx) format**. It will open automatically in presentation mode.

From [Microsoft's site](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/File-formats-that-are-supported-in-PowerPoint-252c6fa0-a4bc-41be-ac82-b77c9773f9dc#ID0EAACAAA=2016,_2013):

> **PowerPoint Show .ppsx**
>
> A presentation that always opens in Slide Show view rather than in Normal view.
>
> Tip:   To open this file format in Normal view so that you can edit the presentation, open PowerPoint. On the File menu, click Open, and then choose the file.

**Note:** If you need macros enabled save as a .ppsm. If you're in PowerPoint 2003 the older format you need is .pps.

Comment: it opens the presentation on screen 2 correctly but you don't get the presenters view on screen 1. Can't see an option for configuring it...

Comment: Hmmm. Seems you're right, there's no way to force visibility of the Presenter View in .ppsx files. That's annoying, and weird. So, my next method would be to save as a .pptm (macro-enabled .pptx) and use VBA to launch the slideshow, which would bring up Presenter View. But irritatingly, PowerPoint doesn't allow you to execute macros on open - so we need another workaround. You could download an auto_open PowerPoint add-in to give this functionality, or you could use something like a macro-enabled Excel file to  call the .pptx on open. Bit painful but it can be done.

Comment: Frustrating, so close and yet so far. I think I'll just leave an instruction on screen 'open powerpoint, click these two buttons' and be done with it. There is only so much you can automate away :) Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by the following

I Added a macro to the Powerpoint presentation

```
Sub Main()
   ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.ShowType = ppShowTypeSpeaker
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run.View.AcceleratorsEnabled = False
    Application.WindowState = ppWindowMinimized
End Sub
```

Then start the powerpoint presentation from the command line with

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/POWERPNT.EXE" /M "Presentation.ppt"  MAIN
```

I used a 2003 presentation in 2016 - so the extension for presentations containing macros is ppt not pptm.

The remaining issue I have is that when I close the presentation it prompts to save - it does not do this if I load and run it using the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm a bit late, but this might be helpful to others.

The best way I could find to start in presenter mode is by pressing `Alt` `F5`. It will start from the first slide, though. 
If you want to start from the current slide, you might need to use the sequence `Alt` `S` `C`. But it doesn't work if you press each individually, they have to be pressed at the same time. Also, this second metho does a weird error sound and I couldn't figure out why.

Anyway, if you are ok about starting on the first slide, `Alt` `S` will do just fine.

Source: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/use-keyboard-shortcuts-to-deliver-powerpoint-presentations-1524ffce-bd2a-45f4-9a7f-f18b992b93a0

Comment: (1) The question says “with no additional user interaction”. It sounds like you’re just offering a different form of user interaction. (2) Or rather, three different forms. What’s the relationship between Alt+F5 and Alt+S?